# Tracking indices with arrays?

Tags: java, python, arrays, hashmap

For tracking indices this achieves a syntax closer to python's dictionaries.

```
byte item0 = 0;
byte item1 = 1;
byte item2 = 2;

byte[] anArray;

anArray = new byte[3];

anArray[item1] = 5;
anArray[item2] = 5;
anArray[item3] = 5;
```

Would this be faster/better than using a hashmap? How/why?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Arrays and hashmaps serve quite different purposes.

Comment: No? If you want a dictionary like capability, use a hashmap.

Comment: If you've been using Python's dicts with keys like `item1`, you haven't been using Python's dicts right. This is a clear case for a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a `HashMap` is you can store a key of any value without having to create a huge array. With your method, if you tried to store a key with Integer.MAX_VALUE for example, you'd need a byte[] of 2^32-1 bytes size. With a HashMap, it will use considerably less memory to store a key like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.